# Android Multiple Packages issue

Tags: android

I have project in my eclipse where I have used multiple packages with the same prefix for all the packages. Here is a screenshot of the structure!

[image: Eclipse IDE screenshot]

The problem is, that when I run the application I get this error message:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.td.bookshelf/com.td.bookshelf.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException)

I have added all the packages manually and copied the class files from the other project.
So I clean built the project and also restarted the eclipse but in vain.

Please help me to get rid of the error.

```
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.td.bookshelf/com.td.bookshelf.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at com.td.bookshelf.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:56)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
08-22 13:43:07.367: E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you give the full stack trace ? Are you sure your problem is coming from your package structure ?

Comment: What is on SplashActivity.java:56 Line ?

Comment: I dont know whether its problem with the new class files i added to the project or the package structure. anyway i dont have any errors in the project.

Comment: What is on SplashActivity.java:56 Line ?

Comment: String file = TDApplication.getAppContext().getFilesDir()
    .getAbsolutePath()
    + "/bookinfo.gmms";

Comment: did you copy the package of splash screen ? if yes put com.td.bookshelf.SplashActivity  in manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error is **not** coming from your package structure.

In the stack trace you can read :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(4900): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(4900):     at com.td.bookshelf.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:56)
```

You're getting a `NullPointerException` when the `onCreate`  method of the SplashActivity is called.

There's probably something wrong in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: String file = TDApplication.getAppContext().getFilesDir()
    .getAbsolutePath()
    + "/bookinfo.gmms";
  bookinfo = new File(file); this is the code i have at the line 56. but can u explain the problem with code. because when i worked with the same code with a single package it was running good.

Comment: What is TDApplication ? Where is it initialized ?

Comment: TDApplication comes from the same package as u can seen in the screenshot. content is: public class TDApplication extends Application {

 private static Context context;

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  TDApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
 }

 public static Context getAppContext() {
  return TDApplication.context;
 }

}

Comment: Try to split the line 56 on several lines. Add null checks and log trace with Log.d("your_message"). Then find out what's null. Maybe getFilesDir() ?

Comment: Thank you! @Timothée Jeannin am able to pass in the code fixing some small bugs in the code.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project. :)